# 389 ldap client authentication issue [CENTOS 7]

Tags: linux, group, ldap, useradd

I have created posix group and posix account also able to successfully authenticate client but client unable to change the password. The error is ``` password change failed: Confidentiality required``passwd: Authentication token manipulation error ```.

**/var/log/secure**

Aug 23 05:08:13 RHELQA passwd: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): password change failed: password change failed: Confidentiality required; user=johanp

Aug 23 05:08:34 RHELQA passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "johanp" does not exist in /etc/passwd

Aug 23 05:09:11 RHELQA passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "johanp" does not exist in /etc/passwd

Aug 23 05:09:11 RHELQA passwd: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): password change failed: password change failed: Confidentiality required; user=johanp

 Aug 23 05:10:29 RHELQA passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "johanp" does not exist in /etc/passwd

Aug 23 05:10:40 RHELQA passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "johanp" does not exist in /etc/passwd

Aug 23 05:10:40 RHELQA passwd: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): password change failed: password change failed: Confidentiality required; user=johanp

Aug 23 06:28:28 RHELQA sshd[3224]: Accepted publickey for ec2-user from x.x.x.x port 5466 ssh2: RSA SHA256:OqK/b0ailCh32//NbcWAgGtzZK35fOVuvqY0xtnNIPI

Aug 23 06:28:28 RHELQA sshd[3224]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ec2-user by (uid=0)

Aug 23 06:28:30 RHELQA sudo: ec2-user : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash

Aug 23 06:29:07 RHELQA sshd[3257]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x  user=johanp

Aug 23 06:29:07 RHELQA sshd[3257]: Accepted password for johanp from x.x.x.x port 5474 ssh2

Aug 23 06:29:07 RHELQA sshd[3257]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user johanp by (uid=0)

Aug 23 06:29:12 RHELQA passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "johanp" does not exist in /etc/passwd

Aug 23 06:29:23 RHELQA passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "johanp" does not exist in /etc/passwd

Aug 23 06:29:23 RHELQA passwd: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): password change failed: password change failed: Confidentiality required; user=johanp

**/etc/pam.d/system-auth**

#%PAM-1.0

# This file is auto-generated.

# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.

auth        required      pam_env.so

auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000

auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass

auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success

auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass

auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow

account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so

account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet

account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so

account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=

password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok

password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok

password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke

session     required      pam_limits.so

-session     optional      pam_systemd.so

session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid

session     required      pam_unix.so

session     optional      pam_ldap.so

**/etc/pam.d/password-auth**

#%PAM-1.0

# This file is auto-generated.

# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.

auth        required      pam_env.so

auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000

auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass

auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success

auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass

auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow

account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so

account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet

account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so

account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=

password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok

password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok

password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke

session     required      pam_limits.so

-session     optional      pam_systemd.so

session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid

session     required      pam_unix.so

session     optional      pam_ldap.so

**/etc/openldap/ldap.conf**

#

# LDAP Defaults

#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details

# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com

#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12

#TIMELIMIT      15

#DEREF          never

TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts

# Turning this off breaks GSSAPI used with krb5 when rdns = false

SASL_NOCANON    on

URI ldap://backup.abc.xyz.local/

BASE dc=abc,dc=xyz,dc=local

Comment: http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/documentation.html

Comment: Why do you have both `pam_sss` and `pam_ldap` entries in the `password-auth` file, but in `system-auth` the `pam_ldap` entries are commented out?

Comment: If you're using `sssd` please include your `sssd.conf` file in your question. If you're using an LDAP connector please include the appropriate LDAP client configuration file. Ensure you redact any passwords you may be using.

Comment: @Roaima I have done fresh client setup again using PAM-LDAP (same method using before), update system-auth and password-auth file here, also add the LDAP.conf file here anything else requires please let me know.

Comment: Now you've changed the configuration new error log please. The old one is now irrelevant. Please format the question. Two stars around a file title. Select a block of code and use the `{}` button top indent 4 spaces.

Comment: /var/log/secure file updated.